# Sent my ETH to Etherium network and see it in Etherscan but it isn't on my Nano

Tags: etherscan

Sent my ETH From Uphold to the Etherium network 0x5aD5b7B9AE09EeCd247ae5Bc4ca4A5950D33f716

I can see the transaction in Etherscan but it is not in the Etherscan account that I made. I'm not sure what I did wrong or where it went. I was attempting to get it to my Ledger Live but it isn't showing. Any help is appreciated.

TransactionID
0x0eb0066193f16ebc3c82c25cb1fb39c45c7922c83ef4bba6a371cf9f4e9bd776

Comment: I just realized I sent it there and then here: 0x11348A2b2bfCbc698d81b7eCA4914f05B21A6Fd3. I really have no idea how to figure this out.

Comment: Can you share the Transaction hash?

Comment: Do you have the mnemonic or private key from the address, or the address is from a centralized service?

Comment: I"m sorry, I didn't see your message until now. Here it is:  Transaction Hash:
0xe01893ebae4c109cd1464360cd6c79445db4727dcda7a684466797184d684af0

Comment: Ismael, I do not know what a mnemonic key is. I know what a private key is but I'm sorry I'm so new to crypto that I don't know what I'm doing. I've moved many tokens to my ledger nano but ETH was completely different.

Comment: I was transferring from an Uphold Wallet and trying to get it on my Nano but I'm not sure where I went wrong. It looks to be on an Etherscan account, but when I created an account, I don't know if I can link it or if I've sent it to someone else's account.